What is the data pulling method for Spark Structure Streaming when consuming Kafka data
    val kafkaDF: DataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "test-topic")
      .option("startingoffsets","earliest")
      .option("group.id", "spark-streaming-kafka")
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "1")
      .load()
    val query: StreamingQuery = ds
      .writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///spark_tutorial/cp")
      .format("console")
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      .start()

I have the following questions regarding the code that simulates real-life scenarios above:
1: Is Spark constantly consuming Kafka data, even without triggering batch calculations? If the amount of data in Kafka is very large, is there a backpressure mechanism to control the read rate.
2: When I specified the maxOffsetsPerTrigger parameter, the maximum amount of data processed for each batch should not exceed this value, right?
3: Consumption of Kafka and batch computing are two parallel tasks, right?
4: If someone could help explain the overall process of consumption and reading, or provide any information links, I would greatly appreciate it.
I tried to control the amount of data processed in each batch through maxOffsetsPerTrigger in this test, which was effective, but I couldn't observe whether Spark was continuously pulling Kafka's data.
